# TeamCity - docker-compose - Cannot map URL

Tags: docker, docker-compose, teamcity

I set up the following docker-compose file to spin up a local teamcity cluster:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
    teamcity:
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:2017.1.2
        volumes:
            - teamcity-server-datadir:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
            - teamcity-server-logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
        ports:
            - 8111:8111
    teamcity-agent:
        image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2017.1.2
        environment:
            SERVER_URL: http://teamcity:8111
        volumes:
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
        depends_on:
            - teamcity
volumes:
    teamcity-server-datadir:
    teamcity-server-logs:
```

If I docker-compose, the containers start just fine but it doesn't connect to teamcity from the browser. When I look up the logs I find:

```
teamcity-agent_1  | [2019-04-02 07:56:24,623]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Failed to obtain server supported protocols via URL http://teamcity:8111/app/agents/protocols: TeamCity Server is starting. Will try later.
teamcity-agent_1  | [2019-04-02 07:56:24,623]   WARN - buildServer.AGENT.registration - Error registering on the server via URL http://teamcity:8111. Will continue repeating connection attempts. Details: server is in a maintenance mode
```

I checked a few SO posts but nothing seems to solve it, the URL is mapped properly. I also added the depends_on onto the agent but it wouldn't help anyway if the server is having issue getting the url.

Any idea?

Comment: I ran exactly what you ran and it works for me. I do see the warnings but it works nonetheless. You can also try to start first "teamcity" and give it a few minutes and then start the rest.

Comment: Thanks @Mihai your comment that it works made me realize whats wrong, it was accessible through localhost:8111 but not on http://teamcity:8111, I just saw the log output and it mislead me, I thought the DNS entry is added per default, I added it manually to etc/hosts. Hilarious how every time I ask something at SO its always something like that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like your teamcity agent starts before server. Here is my docker-compose, it works for me:

```
version: "3"

services:
  teamcity-server:
    container_name: teamcity-server
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-server:2018.2.2
    volumes:
      - ./teamcity-server/data:/data/teamcity_server/datadir
      - ./teamcity-server/logs:/opt/teamcity/logs
    ports:
      - 8111:8111

  teamcity-agent01:
    container_name: teamcity-agent01
    image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:2018.2.2
    environment:
      - SERVER_URL=http://teamcity-server:8111
      - AGENT_NAME=teamcity-agent01
    deploy:
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: '1.0'
          memory: 512M
        reservations:
          cpus: '0.5'
          memory: 256M
```